# XML + SQL: Any free standalone tool capable of injecting results of SQL queries into XML?

Tags: java, sql, xml, xslt

I'm looking for a tool, an offline console program, which would allow me doing something like:

```
<foo attrib="@{SELECT x FROM y WHERE id = 1}">
```

and also

```
<sql:foreach query="SELECT x FROM y">
   <bar attrib="@{x}">
</sql:foreach>
```

Is there something such?
Might also be integrated into XSLT somehow.
Ideally, it should be written in Java, and preferably not in PHP.

Comment: Did you check JSTL's SQL library? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95134/how-does-jstls-sql-tag-work

Comment: Forgot to mention, I want an off-line tool. Some CLI program which would connect to database and fill a template with data.

Comment: I've never heard of anything like that. But maybe you can write your own? You should be able to rip the JSP engine out of Tomcat or Jetty, and wrap it in a stand-alone tool. But it might be easier to do it with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Using [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jstl-137486.html), here is an [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jstlsql/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 9i you can do it right from Oracle:
[Generating XML Data from the Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb12gen.htm)

Comment: I'd rather like something capable of working over JDBC, or ODBC or such. Currently I have HSQL or H2 databases.

Comment: @OndraŽižka: The functions described in the link can be using in SQL Statement which can easily be executed through JDBC. The ResultSet will then contain the XML that was generated.

Comment: I do not want it to be Oracle dependent. It must work with any SQL compliant DB.